Finding DH parameters for robot arm
I am new in robotics. I'm using ikpy to control a 6 servo robot using forward and inverse kinametic.
The robot moves along x, y, and z as desired. However, there are two issues:
1- the robot moves a distance less than required, for example 7 cm along the X-axis when asked it to move 10 cm.
2- changing the orientation leads to the robot's coordinates to change.
the DH table, as I figure out from the provided image:
dlist      = [389, 0, 0, 335, 0, 0];
alist      = [40, 335, 40, 0, 0, 0];
alphalist  = [-np.pi/2, 0, -np.pi/2, np.pi/2, -np.pi/2, 0]
thetalist = [0, -np.pi/2, 0,0,-np.pi/2, np.pi]

where is the problem?
robot arm
solving the problem of finding the DH table for the robot arm
